# Software to record my screen and voice

Tags: gratis, video, screen-recording, windows-10, audio-recording

I want to start online tutorials, so can anyone please suggest to me a video recording software to record my screen and my voice through the microphone.

My requirements are:

- for it to run on Windows 10,
- it to be free,
- it to capture the video of my screen,
- it should record the voice from my microphone,
- and if possible, it should make my editing work simpler.

Comment: please provide more information! like on which OS should it run? what other recommendations do you have...

Answer (score 2):

Assuming that you are using Windows, I personally used [CamStudio](http://camstudio.org/) in the past.  It has features such as annotations, watermarks, cursor and other effects, auto pan, etc., and is free to use.  It will also allow you to record your microphone.

Answer (score 0):

I developed the utility in https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/2009.03.utilityspotlight2.aspx. But it has some issues with Win 10. So I corrected them and published at https://burakuysaler.wordpress.com/2020/03/16/screenrecorder-final-by-burak-uysaler/. As I don’t work at Microsoft anymore, I uploaded it to my Blog. It does everything you look for but Editing.

Comment: Note to all: This brand new Software Recommendations SE community member quickly posted this recommendation multiple times.  Please use caution if visiting the specified site and trying the recommended software.  Please add comments if your experiences are positive or negative. Thank you.